# Delete all foreign key from one model Laravel 8

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

```
class Property extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $guarded=[];

    public function Owner(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Owner::class);
    }
    public function Category(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Categpry::class);
    }
    public function Type(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Type::class);
    }
    public function Uses(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Uses::class);
    }
    public function Other(){
        return $this->hasOne(Other::class);
    }
    public function Street(){
        return $this->hasOne(Street::class);
    }
    public function Part(){
        return $this->hasOne(Part::class);
    }
    public function Pdf(){
        return $this->hasOne(Pdf::class);
    }
    public function Bill(){
        return $this->hasOne(Bill::class);
    }
    public function Numbers(){
        return $this->hasOne(Numbers::class);
    }
    public function Job(){
        return $this->hasOne(Job::class);
    }
}


public function up()
{
    Schema::create('proprietas', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('nomeProprieta')->nullable();
        $table->string('int')->nullable();
        $table->string('floor')->nullable();
        $table->string('street')->nullable();
        $table->string('zip')->nullable();
        $table->string('city')->nullable();
        $table->foreignId('category_id')->constrained();
        $table->foreignId('type_id')->constrained();
        $table->foreignId('uses_id')->constrained();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

when I try to delete a property through the controller it gives me the error Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails.
I also tried with onDelete ('cascade').
If anyone can help me I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your table engine `MyIsam`, change it to `InnoDB` :

```
$table->engine = 'InnoDB';
```

And add `onDelete('cascade')` on your migration :

```
$table->foreignId('category_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
$table->foreignId('type_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
$table->foreignId('uses_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
```

If you want to do that for all table, then change it from  `/config/database.php` file :

```php
'engine' => null,
```

to

```php
'engine' => 'InnoDB',
```